# MySQL query limiting itself to certain dates- why?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find out how much money was spent on salary for the marketing department between the years 1990 and 1992 (using sample database- github.com/datacharmer/test_db)

Here's the whole thing I think should work:

```
SELECT sum(s.salary), d.dept_name, s.from_date, s.to_date 
FROM salaries s 
INNER JOIN dept_emp de ON de.emp_no = s.emp_no 
INNER JOIN departments d ON d.dept_no = de.dept.no 
WHERE dept_name = "Marketing" AND de.from_date > 1990-01-01 AND de.to_date < 1992-12-31;
```

(also tried reversing the signs just in case I have them wrong). I got back a table of nulls.
I tried breaking it down into smaller parts to find the issue. Quick question first:  when talking about dates, does > mean older than?  That's another thing throwing me off. Anyway, I tried:

```
SELECT sum(s.salary), d.dept_name, s.from_date, s.to_date 
FROM salaries s 
INNER JOIN dept_emp de ON de.emp_no = s.emp_no 
INNER JOIN departments d ON d.dept_no = de.dept.no 
WHERE dept_name = "Marketing" AND de.from_date >1990-01-01;
```

and got results but the dates were 1993-08-03 to 1994-08-03.  When I included the other date to limit it to the 2 years requested in the question, I get null which makes sense if it is only grabbing those particular dates, but why is it?  There are definitely plenty more in 1990, 91, and 92.  Am I leaving something out?  TIA!

EDIT-
tried adding quotes to the dates and just got different date results, still not what I specifically need.

```
SELECT sum(s.salary), d.dept_name, s.from_date, s.to_date 
FROM salaries s 
INNER JOIN dept_emp de ON de.emp_no = s.emp_no 
INNER JOIN departments d ON d.dept_no = de.dept.no 
WHERE dept_name = "Marketing" AND de.from_date >='1990-01-01' AND 
de.to_date <= '1992-12-31';
```

results were sum: 54989098, marketing, from_date:1991-09-03, to_date: 1991-09-15

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, **don't link to external sites**), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use double quotes for string or date literals. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL double quotes are usually for identifiers, such as column names. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an "invalid object name" error. Always use single quotes for string or date literals.

Comment: But do quote date literals. What you have there aren't date literals but arithmetic expressions with two subtraction operations, like `1990-01-01` evaluates to `1988` .

Comment: Thanks!  I added single quotes to the dates and now am getting results for 1991-09-03 to 1991-09-15.  Why is it picking random dates?

Comment: There are two things here. First, about how you deal with dates. Second, if you just want the sum, why are you selecting other columns? Sum is aggregated from several rows, the other columns won't make any sense in this context, except if you're planning to use GROUP BY

Comment: Fixed the dates.  I figured I should includ the other rows just so I could verify that I was only getting the department and years I want.  No?  How else will I know I'm getting the right info?

Comment: as  @stickybit already explained without a [mre] it is dificult to understand what you are doing or receiving, also your code shozld produce many errors as mysql expect dates in single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have two problems with dates, you need to put >= (because you inluded the first day of the year) an d<=. Then you need to use quotes for dates.
Besides that, you need to do a group by, if you don´t it will show the first dates it finds. You don´t need the dates in your select:

```
SELECT sum(s.salary), d.dept_name
FROM salaries s 
INNER JOIN dept_emp de ON de.emp_no = s.emp_no 
INNER JOIN departments d ON d.dept_no = de.dept.no 
WHERE dept_name = "Marketing" AND de.from_date >= '1990-01-01' AND de.to_date <= '1992-12-31'
GROUP BY d.dept_name
```